# Can asp.net dynamic data work for more than one database?

Tags: asp.net, dynamic-data

Can I have scaffolding for tables from more than one table in a single asp.net dynamic data website?? If so, how do you do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an article describing it [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/davidebb/archive/2008/12/11/using-dynamic-data-with-multiple-databases.aspx).

And a few more with [this Google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=+dynamic+data+multiple+databases&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a).